# как сделать телепорт объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

я хочу сделать в главном меню игры облака которые типа плывут над океаном. и не знаю как зациклить их движение слева направо . вот код который я нашёл на передвижение объекта в пространстве , и хотел бы узнать лучший способ зацикливания их передвижения (чтобы они уходили в одну сторону и появлялись с другой)

```
public class небо : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 direction;
    public float speed = 2;
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Translate(direction.normalized * speed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы же правильно пишите, что для зацикливания нужно просто когда облако уйдет направо за экран перемещать его в левую часть экрана (точнее в левую часть за экраном, чтобы оно потихоньку выплыло).
Что именно вам не понятно? Как это реализовать? Если да, то реализовать это можно с помощью условия если облако ушло за экран, то переместиться в левую часть экрана:

```
if (transform.position.x > Screen.width) {
    transform.position = new Vector3([число слева экрана], transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

Поэкспериментируйте с числами, чтобы облако появлялось слева от экрана, но, чтобы его не была видно, т.к. оно должно медленно выплывать слева.

Comment: Кирилл, здравствуйте, если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, примите его, поставив галочку. Это даст другим понять, что вопрос решен, а мне - несколько очков опыта за полезный ответ.